# What is the minimum files required of gradle to be committed to VCS?

Tags: git, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradlew

A simple `tree` command after `gradle init` reveals the following files.

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle

2 directories, 6 files
```

The only useful ones that I believe my project should contain is `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`. The rest looks like noise to me. From what I understand gradle wrapper is needed to download the right version of gradle. Isn't there an alternative to commiting these files? especially a `jar`? I'm fine with having a thin wrapper to download the actual wrapper commited to the VCS. Please help me find alternatives to this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> The only useful ones that I believe my project should contain is `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`. The rest looks like noise to me.

True that the build and settings file are the bare minimum needed if you have Gradle installed ***locally***. However, you will also need to make sure that the features/functionality used in the Gradle build file and settings align with the installed version.

Unfortunately, with just those two files, you are not able to tell what version of Gradle you should be using. And if the project is being worked on by multiple persons, then they too would also need the correct version of Gradle installed just to build the project. If they already have Gradle installed, but it's incompatible with the project, then they must installed *another* version of Gradle on their machine just to build the project.

> Isn't there an alternative to commiting these files? especially a jar? I'm fine with having a thin wrapper to download the actual wrapper commited to the VCS

The Gradle wrapper JAR **is** the thin wrapper for Gradle. In fact it's a mere 60KB or so and the [source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/wrapper/src/main/java/org/gradle/wrapper) is small as well. I'm not sure what you mean by "thin" when again, the provided wrapper is thin.

You can try to find an alternative solution, but the recommended way to run Gradle is with the provided Gradle wrapper.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: By thin, I meant any source, script, or some Gradle task that I can execute to download the actual wrapper. Something about committing binaries to VCS doesn't sit right with me.